# How to serve robots.txt from a javascript webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, robots.txt

I have been battling with this, but all in vain. I am taking over this Webpack project that needs to have a robots.txt file running from its directory level, but I cannot get its routing to work. I dropped it next to where index.html is served from,  but I keep getting Error Cannot Get robots.txt when I try to load or access it.

Is there any documentations or examples showing how to serve robots.txt from a Webpack projects?

Thanks,

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservercontentbase

Comment: Thanks, looked at the docs but kinda not clear. Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried using   devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
},  as suggested, but it does not load robots.txt from the public folder?

Answer (score 8):

Use CopyWebpackPlugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/

```
$ npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

In your webpack.config.js file ...

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
...
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: 'source', to: 'dest' },
      { from: 'other', to: 'public' },
      { from: 'src/robots.txt', to: 'robots.txt' }
    ]),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Is this still the best way in webpack 5?

Answer (score 1):

For me was solution

```
        const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
        ...
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: "robots.txt", to: "robots.txt" },
            ],
        }),
```

And yes, I think that this is still the best way in webpack 5.